# Run command every time regex is matched, reading from stdin which does not have an EOF

Tags: bash, d-bus, notifications

I am attempting to write a BASH script that creates a timestamp (to be written to file) every time a certain string is found within the output of dbus-monitor (parameters specified later in post). The main purpose of my script is to save the time (including milliseconds) and date whenever a song starts playing on Spotify, as it utilizes notifications.

The following command outputs `string "Spotify"` whenever a song beings playing.

```
dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify' | grep 'string "Spotify"'
```

My attempt:

```
search='string "Spotify"'
found=$(dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify' | grep 'string "Spotify"')

while [ ${search} == ${found} ]; do
    date -u +%Y%M%d-%H%M%S.%N >> timestamp.txt
done
```

I am assuming the reason of my code's dysfunction is that dbus-monitor continuously runs, therefore preventing the while loop from executing.

Comment: Read `man dbus-monitor dbus`.

Comment: Read `man grep`, especially about the `--line-buffered` option.

Comment: line-buffered doesn't help either. grep don't give return code per line (never solved) https://stackoverflow.com/q/56675613

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
stdbuf -oL dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify' |
while grep -q 'string "Spotify"'; do
    date -u +%Y%M%d-%H%M%S.%N >> timestamp.txt
done
```

EDIT after @StéphaneChazelas comments:

```
stdbuf -oL dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify' |
grep --line-buffered 'string "Spotify"' |
while read trash; do
    stdbuf -oL date -u +%Y%M%d-%H%M%S.%N >> timestamp.txt
done
```

+1 other answers but I keep this for completeness

Comment: `grep -q` reads its input in large blocks though. If in that block there are several matches, only the first one will cause a timestamp to be added to `timestamp.txt`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Right, just edited. I think this forces grep to read line by line.

Comment: `stdbuf  -oL` forces `dbus-monitor` to buffer its output by line. But `dbus-monitor` already doesn't buffer its output. Still, if `dbus-monitor` outputs more than one match into the pipe by the time `grep` reads that output from the other end, `grep` will read both and the second will be dropped.

Comment: I think I disagree with the first part. the output is buffered because dbus-monitor is connected to a pipe. anyway, I agree about the second one.

Comment: Applications using stdio for I/O would start buffering their output by block instead of by line when it doesn't go to a tty device (and a pipe or regular file is not a tty device). `dbus-monitor` does use stdio, but the first thing it does upon starting is `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0)` to disable buffering regardless of whether stdout is a tty or not.

Answer (score 9):

Use `awk` instead of `grep` - something like:

```
dbus-monitor ... | awk '/Spotify/ {
    system("date -u +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.%N >> timestamp.txt")
  }'
```

(note the use of `%Y%m%d` instead of `%Y%M%D` - capital-M is minutes, not months. And capital-D is equivalent to `%m/%d/%y`)

This will use awk's `system()` function to run the date command in a sub-shell whenever it sees "Spotify" in the input.  Alternatively, use awk's built-in date-formatting and redirection:

```
dbus-monitor ... | awk '/Spotify/ {
    print strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") >> "timestamp.txt"
  }'
```

This version won't print nanoseconds in the timestamp because `strftime()` doesn't support `%N`.

Alternatively, use perl instead of awk.  That would allow you to use perl's [Desktop::Notify](https://metacpan.org/release/Desktop-Notify) module to get the notifications or [Net::DBus](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-DBus) to communicate directly with dbus.

Answer (score 9):

Since you have GNU utilities, you could do something like:

```
dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify' |
  sed -un 's/^.*string "Spotify".*$/now/p' |
  stdbuf -oL date -uf - +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.%N >> timestamp.txt
```

`dbus-monitor` already [disables buffering](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/dbus/dbus/-/blob/151574605eeab7ec37846b8f926b89d42fc08ae4/tools/dbus-monitor.c#L374), so `stdbuf -oL` is not necessary there.

The `-u` option of GNU `sed` disables output buffering and also makes it read its input one byte at a time when it's not seekable here. We don't need the latter but we need the former so that it outputs a line as soon as it reads it.

Here, we get `sed` to output `now` each time it finds a line that contains `string "Spotify"`.

That `now` is fed to `date`. With `-f -`, `date` reads the `date` to print from stdin. For each `now` it reads, it prints the current time in the format specified. With `stdbuf -oL` we make sure that output makes it to the `timestamp.txt` file straight away instead of in chunks.

If you do want to run any arbitrary command, instead of just outputting the current time, with, zsh/bash/ksh93, you could do:

```
while IFS= read -ru3 line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
  any arbitrary command
done 3< <(
  dbus-monitor --session interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',member='Notify' |
  grep --line-buffered 'string "Spotify"'
)
```

Comment: Since we're using GNU `sed`, we can even have it execute the command, with a `s///e` substitution.

Comment: What is the reason for the usage of file descriptor 3, occurring in - ru3 and 3<?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it looks like `dbus-monitor` already provides timestamps (in epoch time + microseconds). So you may not need to execute `date` for each match. Perhaps the match expression can narrowed down with, for example, `arg0='Spotify'`.

Check the output from this:

```
dbus-monitor "
  type='method_call',
  interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications',
  member='Notify',
  arg0='Spotify'"
```

Hopefully you will only see dbus messages relating to notifications from Spotify (unable to test this - it's just a guess from looking at the [dbus spec](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-routing)). If this works, then the following may be suitable:

```
dbus-monitor --profile "type='method_call',
  interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications', member='Notify', arg0='Spotify'" |
gawk -F '\t' '
  $NF=="Notify" {
    secs = usecs = $2
    sub(/^[^.]+/,"",usecs)
    print strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S",int(secs),"UTC") usecs
    fflush()
  }' > timestamp.log
```

Using `--profile` for the output format as it seems simpler to parse than the default `--monitor` output. Piping to GNU `awk` to extract and format the timestamp.